# The set of Vitali

Tags: measure-theory

I have problems with this exercise

> Let $V\subseteq{}(0,1) $ the set of Vitali. Suppose that $A \in  \mathcal{B}_L$ such that $A \subseteq{V}$. Prove that $\ell(A) = 0$

I need any hint

Comment: @manuelcerda: Hint: The trick tp the solution pointed out by Kaira is to see that (in your notation) the sets $A+r$ (where $r$ ranges over all rational numbers in (-1,1)$ are disjoint.